# How can I set value in a select with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want set a option from a select getting id, and all others objects to a directive and show it.
Let me explain:
I'm trying edit a object "dynamically"
Here is my obj structure

```
[
  {
     nome: "name",           //phone company
     codigo: "id",           //that isn't sequential (14, 16, 29...)
     categoria: "category",  //cellphone or landline
     preco: "price"          //float digits
  }
]
```

"Contato" is my contact object, structure:

```
[
  {
     nome:"name",
     telefone:"1233-1233",
     data:"2016-06-25T22:03:21.508Z",
     operadora:
          {
               nome:"name",
               codigo:"(code)", -> int
               categoria:"category",
               preco:"(price)" -> float
     },
     serial:"<H_ZZ<ET9B" -> randomic ASCII generated
  }
]
```

Price is decorative, all things don't make sense, just for "learning"

Then I call directive:

```
<ui-accordions>
    <ui-accordion ng-repeat="contato in contatos | filter:{nome: criterioBusca} | orderBy:criterioDeOrdenacao:direcaoOrdenacao" username= contato.nome serial=  contato.serial  telefone= contato.telefone data = contato.data operadora = contato.operadora operadoras=operadoras >
    </ui-accordion>
</ui-accordions>
//orderBy:criterioDeOrdenacao: direcaoOrdenacao -> orderBy: orderCritery: orderDirection
//filter:{nome: criterioBusca} -> name: searchCritery
```

I use directive "uiAccordions" because can open one accordion each

I use directive "uiAccordion" to get params and show with external Url (html file)
My select in html external file (directive use that)

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="contatoOperadoras" ng-options="operadoraTemp.nome + ' (' + (operadoraTemp.preco | currency) +')' for operadoraTemp in operadoras | orderBy:'nome'"> 
     <option value=""></option> <!-- This is who i want select  -->
</select>
```

I put that gay in uiAccordion call (look ui declaration)

```
operadora = contato.operadora
```

This give me actual operadora object (phone company) of this contato (contact/user)
All this is just learning but i can't solve that. I think if I create other param index and pass in the option tag (value), but how?

I want show like that
(selected {{operadora.nome}})

Sorry for a not grammatical english, but here on my country english is the last language encouraged by authorities (like in high school, like that), i'm learning by myself. Any doubt about code/grammatical, ask =)

Thanks guys.
[]'s
Best regards, Luan

Comment: Solved =) Thanks if u're reading. []'s

Comment: insert your answer here....for others !! ... [solved] ... not answer

Comment: I post solution above. Read [@Soluion]. @edit and i pointed modifications, but thanks anyway. []'s

Comment: What Maher means is that we prefer answers to be posted in the answer section, below. I have done that for you just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*

I solved this.

View:

```
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="operadora" ng-init="operadora = operadoracod" > 
        <option ng-selected="{{operadora.codigo == operadoracod}}" <!-- here --> ng-repeat = "operadora in operadoras | orderBy:'nome'" value="{{operadora.codigo}}">{{operadora.nome + ' (' + (operadora.preco | currency) +')'}}</option>
    </select>
```

Index:

```
<ui-accordions>
        <ui-accordion ng-repeat="contato in contatos | filter:{nome: criterioBusca} | orderBy:criterioDeOrdenacao:direcaoOrdenacao" username= contato.nome serial=  contato.serial  telefone= contato.telefone data = contato.data operadoracod = contato.operadora.codigo <!-- here -->operadoras=operadoras >
        </ui-accordion>
    </ui-accordions>
```

Directive:

```
scope: {
        username: "=",
        data: "=",
        serial: "=",
        telefone: "=",
        operadoras: "=",
        operadoracod: "=" //here
    }
```